# add custom field in magento admin user account form

Tags: magento, admin, custom-fields, account

How to add custom field in Magento admin user account form, I've tried many options but am not successfully generate,please guide me to add custom field in Magento admin user account form.

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Title'),
'class' => 'required-entry',
'required' => true,
'name' => 'title',
));
```

Comment: Custom Field or Attribute ?

Comment: custom field in magento admin user like                              custom field                                                     User Name * 
First Name * 
Last Name * 
Email * 
New Password 
Password Confirmation

Comment: As you are the new user on stackoverflow . so, please complete your profile detail.

Comment: "Admin user account form" in System -> Permission -> User -> Account Information?